# How to display a couple pages of text in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, text, scroll

I've got an information page which has about 3 pages worth of text to display.

What would be the best method to display all this text in an iOS application coded in swift?

I have been trying to do it with scroll view but I can't fit all the text into one label on one screen. And all the tutorials I'm following say to set the scroll view to the size of the label. But the thing is my text is so long that it would fill the screen several times.

How could this be accomplished so that no matter which device size screen it's being viewed on it will fit all my text and be scrollable vertically?

I can't seem to get it working with a scrollview :/

Comment: Are you using a label or a text view?

Comment: label, wouldn't textview make it editable?

Answer (score 2):

Put the content in an HTML file, and render it using WKWebView: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView

Comment: I'd like it to be accessible without an internet connection is there any other alternative?

Comment: Put the HTML file in your app bundle.  You can render local HTML files with WKWebView too.  Use NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource to get the URL for a local HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a text view non editable.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe also explain that a UITextView is itself a child of the UIScrollView https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/

Comment: I've made the textview uneditable and put it inside a scroll view (as a child) and for some reason I can't scroll down. I'm having trouble with the auto layout settings most likely.  Is there any tutorial on how to accomplish what I want to? I can't seem to find any good literature

Comment: Try not putting the textview inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also.. Maybe you could use table view and add contents programmatically.. hope it could add to your imagination.

Comment: I might have to go that route but I'd prefer to avoid that If possible.